# Multiplicative inverses why two z in this formula?

Tags: inverse, cryptography

I am studying maths and have the following question set by my professor.

I thought the answer was 5, because:
3 . 5 = 15, and 15 mod 7 is 1. 
Since 1 mod 7 = 1 that means they match.

However, I looked at the formula and noticed both variables are z, which leads me to believe they both have to be 3. Look for the red in the picture.
[image]
I guess my question is what the answer is, and why?

Comment: You may let $z^{-1} = x$ and proceed. $z^{-1}$ is different, it is not $\dfrac{1}{z}$.

Comment: @plagiarism The $z$ values don't have to be the same (and, in this case, are not) in each question. They're just reusing a variable letter.

Comment: @rsadhvika $z^{-1}=x$ is a bad idea, because $x$ is used for the modulus in the first equation.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that! bad idea agree :) Ty @a

Comment: The question is so badly worded that I find it hard to believe it came from a maths professor.

Comment: It came from a cryptography professor. I feel like every university I go to I end up dealing with poorly explained topics.

Answer (score 1):

The first line, where you have underlined it in red, is the definition of $z^{-1}$.  The next two lines are problems you are to do.  Your answer of $5$ for the first is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$3^{-1}\cong 5\pmod 7$ and $2^{-1}\cong3\pmod 5$.  The first is because $3\cdot 5=15\cong1\pmod7$.  The second because $2\cdot3=6\cong1\pmod5$.

Comment: If my answer to the question is correct (I said it was 5) I do not understand why my professor had two variables with the same letter z, when clearly they hold different numbers?! :'-(

Comment: @plagiarism Mira and Mira's husband are two different people. Do you see that?

Comment: Two different problems.

Comment: Okay. So just to double check, my answer of 5 was correct, and z and z^-1 are two different numbers?

Comment: Yes.  $z$ and $z^{-1}$ are different;   and there are two problems.

Comment: The last question in the image has no answer, am I correct?

Comment: @plagiarism It's 3.

Comment: Doh, no need to explain I already see my error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the z variables are different numbers, because one z is to the power of negative one.

The answer 5 was also correct for the example question.